# Databricks schema enforcement issues

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, database-schema, azure-databricks, delta-lake

As suggested in the article about [schema enforcement](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html), a declared schema helps detecting issues early.

The two issues described below *however* are preventing me from creating a descriptive schema.

**Comments on a table column are seen as a difference in the schema**

```
# Get data
test_df = spark.createDataFrame([('100000146710')], ['code'])
# ... save
test_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save('/my_table_location')

# Create table: ... BOOM
spark.sql("""
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
       code STRING COMMENT 'Unique identifier'
   ) USING DELTA LOCATION '/my_table_location'
""")
```

This will fail with **AnalysisException: The specified schema does not match the existing schema at /my_table_location** . The only solution I found is to drop the columnt comments.

**Not null struct field shows as nullable**

```
json_schema = StructType([
  StructField("code", StringType(), False)
])

json_df = (spark.read
  .schema(json_schema)
  .json('/my_input.json')
)
json_df.printSchema()
```

will show

```
root
  |-- code: string (nullable = true)
```

So despite the schema declaration stating that a field is *not null*, the field shows as *nullable* in the dataframe. Because of this, adding a *NOT NULL* constraint on the table column will trigger the **AnalysisException** error.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

With the execution of

```
test_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save('/my_table_location')
```

You have already created a new Delta table with its specific schema as defined by `test_df`.  This new table `` delta.`/my_table_location` `` already has the schema of `code STRING`.

If you would like to create a comment within the schema, perhaps first create the table as you would like it defined, e.g.

```
spark.sql("""
   CREATE TABLE my_table 
     code STRING COMMENT 'unique identifier' 
    USING DELTA LOCATION '/my_table_location'
""")
```

And then insert your data from your test_df into it, e.g.

```
test_df.createOrReplaceView("test_df_view")

spark.sql("""
INSERT INTO my_table (code) SELECT code FROM test_df_view
""")
```